# Como pasar parametros a otra ruta con jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estoy tratando de redireccionar a otra ruta según la opción que elija, pero a su vez pasar unos valores, en este caso unos ID.

O sea tengo 2 `<select>` donde elijo la sede y el periodo que deseo imprimir. Esos id quiero pasarlos a otra ruta y he intentado hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function (){
    var IDSEDE = document.getElementById("sedee").value;
    //var Periodoid = document.getElementById("idperiodos").value;
     var Periodoid = $("#idperiodos").val();
     // console.log(IDSEDE,Periodoid);
  Swal
    .fire({
        title: "Donde deseas imprimir este reporte",
        text: "",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Pdf",
        cancelButtonText: "Excel",
    })
    .then(resultado => {
        if (resultado.value) {
          
            var url = '{{  route('reporteadmitidos.pdf', ['id' => 'IDSEDE','idPeriodo' => 'Periodoid'])}}';
             console.log(url); 
         url= url.replace('IDSEDE',IDSEDE); 
         url= url.replace('Periodoid',Periodoid); 
            // Hicieron click en "Sí"
               window.location.href = url;
            
        } else {0
            // Dijeron que no
             window.location.href = "AspiAdmitido.export";
            console.log("*NO se elimina la venta*");
        }
    }); 
})
```

Eso en parte funciona pero al hacerle un DD me muestra lo siguiente...

```
    #parameters: array:2 [▼
          "id" => "3"
          "amp;idPeriodo" => "2"
        ]
      }
```

No entiendo porque el **id** del periodo aparece con ese **"amp"**. Cuando lo quiero pasar a una variable me dice null.

Comment: Ese **amp** parece un resto en alguna parte del caracter **&**, pues `&amp;` es un entity que se escribe `&` en HTML.  Mira a ver si tienes más **&** de los que debes en alguna parte, pues en el código que has puesto no lo se ver

Comment: @masterguru como estas?? la verdad no se porque pasa eso  ;S var url = '{{  route('reporteadmitidos.pdf', ['id' => 'IDSEDE','idPeriodo' => 'Periodoid'])}}'; sucede justo cuando coloco esto.
conoces otro metodo que funcione??